# How to test a program in bash? (functional testing)

Tags: linux, bash, testing, automated-tests

I wrote a program in C named `gcd` that return the greatest common divisor that I call with:

```
$ ./gcd 42 36
6
```

I could test these input with:

```
#!/bin/bash 

[[ $(./a.out 42 36) == "6" ]] || exit 1
[[ $(./a.out 42 11) == "1" ]] || exit 1
```

Unfortunately with this I do not have any summary such as

```
ran 11 tests, 0 failures, 11 successful tests
```

Is there any very simple template/framework to do such testing at program level (not unit testing)?

Comment: at what Point you get this summary

Comment: Have a look at [shunit2](https://github.com/kward/shunit2/) - it's a test framework for Bash.

Comment: https://blog.esciencecenter.nl/testing-shell-commands-from-python-2a2ec87ebf71

Comment: With the `|| exit` approach, you could just return a different code for which test failed. If tests 25 fails then `|| exit 25`? Another wrapper script, or use a function, would then detect that failure and print it. You can't summarise if you exit after the first failure anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following (altho a bit of a hack right?)

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A messages
declare -A statuses

[[ 0 -eq 0 ]] && statuses["test_name_here"]=0 || {
    messages["test_name_here"]="Failed to divide 1023/123";
    statuses["test_name_here"]=1
}
[[  0 -eq 1 ]] && statuses["test_name2_here"]=0 || {
    messages["test_name2_here"]="Failed to divide asd/123";
    statuses["test_name2_here"]=1
}

exit_code=0
pass=0
fail=0

# Iterate statuses by key!
for i in "${!statuses[@]}"
do
  echo -n "$i - "
  if [ ${statuses[$i]} -eq 0 ]; then
      echo "PASS"
      pass=$((pass + 1))
  else
      echo "FAIL message=${messages[$i]}"
      exit_code=1
      fail=$((fail + 1))
  fi
done

echo "Passed $pass, Failed $fail"
exit $exit_code
```

In this script you can run your tests, name them and track their success or failure. At the end I print the stats and exit with the right code (!=0 if any test failed). Output:

```
$ ~/tmp/test.sh
test_name_here - PASS
test_name2_here - FAIL message=Failed to divide asd/123
Passed 1, Failed 1
```

Comment: note: adding total is a minor change to print the length of statuses hashmap